# Android - FlipView reset by itself

Tags: java, android, sdk, flipview

I'm pretty new in Android development, so i'm not sure what is happening.
I have made an app with a fixed part outside and a part inside that switch a FlipView during onCreate event and onNavigationItemSelected. All work fine, exept when i flip my phone to landscape and back, the flipview automaticaly return on it's original page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Activity recreated, when you turn device. Read [THIS](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) to solve this problem. You need to implement onSaveInstanceState function.